# make: *** No rule to make target `gcc', needed by `all'. Stop

Tags: c, makefile

I am going through an eg pgm to create a make file.

http://mrbook.org/tutorials/make/

My folder eg_make_creation contains the following files,

```
desktop:~/eg_make_creation$ ls
factorial.c  functions.h  hello  hello.c  main.c  Makefile
```

#### Makefile

```
all:gcc -c main.c hello.c factorial.c -o hello
```

error:

```
desktop:~/eg_make_creation$ make all
make: *** No rule to make target `gcc', needed by `all'.  Stop.
```

Please help me understand to compile this program.

Comment: please read the linked document carefully again, what it says about formatting the Makefile; whitespace charcacters (newline and tabs especially) are important and can't simply be omitted

Comment: `all:` isn't a command line...

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The syntax of makefiles is very strict:

```
target:dependencies
        build_rules
# ^ this space here _needs_ to be a tab.
```

What you wrote makes `all` depend on `gcc`, `-c`, ... which are not valid targets.

What you need is something like:

```
all: hello

hello: factorial.c  functions.h hello.c  main.c 
         gcc -o hello factorial.c hello.c  main.c
```

(If you want to compile and link in one step, don't use the `-c` switch).

Comment: I always land on this page because I am attempting to build `.c` files with `g++` compiler.

Answer (score 4):

Mat nailed it.

In my particular case, I'm using vi and have the expandtab enabled by default!!

To see if this issue applies to you, open vi and do:

```
:set list
```

If you don't see a ^I where a tab should be, then you most likely have the et enabled.

To disabled it just:

```
:set expandtab!
```

Maybe it helps somebody else as well.

Answer (score 0):

Another reason is because you have the wrong name in the list of source files.  (nameWrong.o instead of nameRight.o)  That was my issue.

Answer (score 0):

`After all:` everything is target, shows dependency anything written after that should present that directory,as in your code `gcc`(as a file is not present) like wise `-c` too
`all:gcc -c main.c hello.c factorial.c -o hello` correct one is 
`all:main.c hello.c factorial.c -o hello`
please Read more about it [GNU MAKE](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Automatic-Variables.html)