# Makefile for pthreads

Tags: c++, c, linux, makefile, pthreads

I am trying to compile a pthread example, but am getting the following error:

```
make: *** No rule to make target `example.cpp', needed by `example.o'.  Stop.
```

This is my makefile:

```
CC = g++
CCFLAGS = -Wall

example: example.o
        $(CC) $(CCFLAGS) -o example example.o -pthread

example.o: example.cpp
        $(CC) $(CCFLAGS) -c example.cpp -pthread

clean:
        - rm *.o
        - rm example
```

I included the -pthread flag, I am not sure what else it wants in order to compile.  Anyone have any ideas?  Thank you very much.

Comment: Before `$(CC)`, do you have tabs or spaces?

Comment: If you copy-pasted your makefile contents here, then you do not have tabs.

Comment: Remove everything before the calls to `$(CC)` and `rm` and put a tab. I had once the very same problem and the cause was I copy-pasted the makefile.

Comment: I have double and triple checked, they are all tabs =(

Comment: I have tried a little example (merely printing out "Hello world") with that Makefile and with MingW it works...

Comment: Mmm, check if the `cpp` is really named `example`. Maybe there's a typo in the name. And check if you're calling `make` in the right directory.

Comment: Seems that `make` can not find your `example.cpp` file. Check that it is in the same folder as your `Makefile`.

Comment: Read the error, what is it telling you? You have no `example.cpp` file. This is nothing to do with pthreads

Comment: Just finding this after a google, super helpful for writing a makefile with threads!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As it says, there is no example.cpp in the current directory.

Do a ls in the current directory and post here.

Comment: I was so tired when I posted this that I didn't realize that I had example, not example.cpp......thank you!!! I feel really slow now, but I'm really glad it worked!

Answer (score 0):

check http://www.cse.iitd.ernet.in/~dheerajb/Pthreads/Document/Pthreads_Information.html
It has an example for pthread makefile http://www.cse.iitd.ernet.in/~dheerajb/Pthreads/codes/C/Makefile.pthread, you need to use `-lpthread`

Comment: With MingW using `-pthread` just yields a warning, not an error. Do this produce an error in other systems?

Comment: well it seems then the problem is in makefile formatting. i just tried it by copy pesting, but got same error, then tried it rewriting same thing, worked nicely, make is very strict about the formatting, can you check if you are not replacing tabs with spaces (from my earlier experience) in editor, check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8559033/make-no-rule-to-make-target-gcc-needed-by-all-stop